# Can't install py4jdbc

Tags: python, pip, py4j

I have to install py4jdbc module in python on windows 10, but i am having the followings errors when i try to use pip install py4jdbc or from the source:

Error 1: "The executable sbt cannot be found"

[Pip Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULLnk.png)

Error 2: "the file doesn't exist..."

[Error From source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tnui.png)

I have sbt already install and in the path.

Is there something i am missing?

Comment: Do you have `sbt.exe` in the `%PATH%`? Can you run `sbt.exe` from the terminal?

Comment: yes , i can run sbt from the terminal and even do the hello world in scala.

Comment: `python -c "from distutils.spawn import find_executable; print(find_executable('sbt'))"`

Comment: When i run this on cmd i get None, what does it means?

Comment: You don't have `sbt.exe` in `%PATH%`. It could be `sbt.bat` or `sbt.cmd` but not `sbt.exe`. And `py4jdbc` uses function `find_executable` that on w32 looks for only `.exe`.

Comment: Thank you, where should i download sbt.exe? Because as you said, in my instalation dir,i only have sbt.bat

Answer (score 0):

It seems `py4jdbc` was not tested on Windows as it uses a function `distutils.spawn.find_executable` that on w32 looks only for `sbt.exe` while you have `sbt.bat`.

My advice is to try to fix `py4jdbc`. Download it with `pip download py4jdbc` (it also downloads dependency `py4j`), unpack the archive `py4jdbc-0.1.6.8.tar.gz` and edit `setup.py`: at line 28 replace `'sbt'` with `'sbt.bat'`. Install with `pip install .` (<- the dot at the end means "the current directory".)